# Twitter Bootstrap Popovers not working after filtering on Datatables

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, popover

I've got a `datatable` with pagination and I've got anchors with popovers generated for each row but popovers are only shown on first results page. While filtering results or moving to another results page, popovers don't appear.

I wonder if someone already had the same problem and what I can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to ditscheri 's solution is using [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
  $(".js_popover").popover({ html:true });
  // $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({ html:true });
},
```

Answer (score 3):

The DataTables Plugin destroys and rebuilds the DOM elements on filtering/sorting. You might get along with something like this:

```
var myTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
/* Apply the popover using the API */
myTable.$("[id^=popover-]").popover();
```

Here's some documentation on it: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_post_init.html

If it doesn't help, you might want to provide a basic example of you code.

Comment: Thanks ditscheri.
In fact, in my example i create the table like in your example, and after that, i set to every anchor id a popover element. In fact this works on first results page, but doesn't work for the following ones.
example: 
$("#popover"+objid).popover({options});
$(this).popover();

Comment: Have you tried the syntax above? `myTable.$("[id^=popover-]").popover();` should add the popover dynamically to every element with an id, that starts with `popover-`.

Comment: Yes i've tried but it doesn't work. Returns an error message: "myTable is not a function".

Comment: Did you add the first line of my code example as well? I've edited my original answer. Did you test the complete snippet?

Comment: Yes, i've done exactly that with my example but it didn't work! :/

Comment: I just noted, that I used an extra hyphen, that might cause the trouble. Looking at your first reply, it should propably be `"[id=^popover]"` without the hyphen. Maybe this was the last problem. If it still doesn't work, could you provide a link to your project?

Comment: Further to the above, rather than using an ID as a selector I used `myTable.$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

Answer (score 0):

(Bootstrap 4, DataTables 1.10.25)

In my situation popovers worked on the first page - but NOT subsequent pages (page number > 1).

For my application this code allowed popovers to work on subsequent pages:

```
const rows = $("#tbl").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
$(rows).find('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html: true, trigger: 'hover', placement: 'bottom', content: function () { return $(this).data('content') ; } });
```