# Bootstrap Popover in JQuery Datatable doesn't work after search

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-popover

I have a HTML table:

```
<table id="PeopleTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Pop</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>Michael</td><td><button class='popoverButton'>Popover</button></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And I want to use the DataTables plug-in to have search, order and filter functionality. I also want to use Bootstrap to show a popover when the button is clicked, so I've tried this:

```
var peopleTable = $('#PeopleTable').DataTable({
            drawCallback: function () {
                $('.popoverButton').popover({
                    "html": true,
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    placement: 'left',
                    "content": function () {
                        return "<div>Popover content</div>";
                    }
                }).click(function (e) {
                    $(this).popover('toggle');
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem is: when I perform a search, column sorting or any operation with the DataTable, the Popover stops working.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxrjm530/) if you want to try it.

Is "draw" the correct event to perform this or should I use another one? Am I missing any other thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated JS fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/dxrjm530/4/

You just need to take out your click event of button, because after sorting, it is getting called twice, due to drawcallback method of datatable.

```
        $('#PeopleTable').DataTable({
            drawCallback: function () {
                $('.popoverButton').popover({
                    "html": true,
                    trigger: 'manual',
                    placement: 'left',
                    "content": function () {
                        return "<div>Popover content</div>";
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        $('#AddRow').on('click', function(){
            var peopleTable = $('#PeopleTable').DataTable();
            peopleTable.row.add(
                ['1',
                "David", 
                "<button class='popoverButton'>Popover</button>"]
            ).draw();
        });



        $('table').on('click', function(e){
        if($('.popoverButton').length>1)
        $('.popoverButton').popover('hide');
        $(e.target).popover('toggle');

        });
```

Comment: I need to declare the click event after the Datatable is drawed, because I'm adding rows dynamically. Take a look at [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxrjm530/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72850074/979174

```
const rows = $("#tbl").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
$(rows).find('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html: true, trigger: 'hover', placement: 'bottom', content: function () { return $(this).data('content') ; } });
```